# How can I get values from NotImplementedError in sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy, equation, algebra

I'm using this code:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x')

function = input("Insert function: ")

def gx(function,x):
    return solve(function,x,dict=True)

print(gx(function,x))
```

When I write **cos(x)+x** I get this error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/raulpenate/Documents/pyhton/MetodosNumericos/Tareas/testing.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(gx(function,x))
  File "/home/raulpenate/Documents/pyhton/MetodosNumericos/Tareas/testing.py", line 9, in gx
    return solve(function,x)
  File "/home/raulpenate/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 1095, in solve
    solution = _solve(f[0], *symbols, **flags)
  File "/home/raulpenate/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 1714, in _solve
    raise NotImplementedError('\n'.join([msg, not_impl_msg % f]))
NotImplementedError: multiple generators [x, cos(x)]
No algorithms are implemented to solve equation x + cos(x)
```

And I want to get that value from the

```
NotImplementedError: multiple generators [x, cos(x)]
```

Especifically that **cos(x)**, how can I get that value from there?. I can't find that part in the [documentation](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/sympy/tutorial/solvers.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NotImplementedError` will occur if sympy can't find an analytic solution. You can solve this numerically instead:

```
from sympy import nsolve, cos, Symbol
x = Symbol("x")
nsolve(cos(x) + x, 0) # -0.739085133215161
```

This problem <s>won't</s> is unlikely to have a closed form in terms of elementary functions, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46934/what-is-the-solution-of-cosx-x/1174794#1174794 and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html

Comment: That is really close from what I want.
I want to create a simple code to ask to the user to insert a function and then get the root using the fixed point theorem, so I need to clear x from an ecuation to be able to do that, do you have any idea how?, or alternative?

Comment: I gonna give you the points as a resolved answer, for trying to help me, what I am looking for I discovered I doesn't exist xD, if there were a library to clear x from expresions perfectly, the math would've been already solved.

Anyway thank you man.

Comment: @Raul Penate you could do something like this: `eq = sympify(user_input_string); variables = list(eq.free_symbols); assert len(variables) == 1; x = variables[0]; nsolve(eq, x, 0)` but note that passing untrusted strings to `sympify` (or any sympy function) is a security vulnerability (`sympify` invokes python `eval`).

Comment: but actually `nsolve` doesn't require specifying the free variable `x` so maybe I've misunderstood your question. In any case you can find 'x' using `expr.free_symbols` or `expr.atoms(Symbol)` (the latter might return bound variables)